# ASPXAUTH cookie not being stored after CORS request

Tags: javascript, wcf, cookies

I've been asked to write a javascript/HTML front-end to connect to a set of WCF services.  I can use Postman to hit the Logon service and I can see that on a valid logon, two cookies are set `.ASPXAUTH` and `ASP.NET_SessionId`.

When I hit the same service from my javascript code, I get a `200` response and in the network section of Chrome developer tools, I can see the `Set-Cookie` header in the response for each of the two cookies.

However, the cookies do not get stored in the browser so subsequent requests to the server fail because they lack the cookie credentials.

The client app is on a different domain (https://localhost:44357) than the server (http://localhost:3101) so CORS is in play.  The client call is made using `aurelia-http-client` which is a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest`.  I'm using `.withCredentials()` which is supposed to add the `credentials: true` header.  You can see that it is being included:

[image]

The Server is configured for CORS like so:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://localhost:44357");
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,OPTIONS");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type,Accept,credentials");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age","1728000");
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  Why aren't the cookies from the WCF Server being stored by the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In playing around, I found that moving the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header outside the if statement did the trick.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",...)
    //Had to move this line outside of the if statement
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
    if(...)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```